# What are the new features of ADO.NET 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, ado.net

I was asked by interviewer that what are new features of ADO.NET 2.0?

I replied (A) SQLConnection (B) SQL Command (C) Data Adapter, dataset & data reader.

But he said, those features were already there in ADO.NET 1.1

let me know if any inputs.

Thanks!

Comment: Strange interview question, given that ADO.NET 2.0 is five years old.

Comment: @John - not really. It's constantly depressing to me how long it takes for old technologies to be superseded in the real world. In my last job I wound up working on Visual C++ 6 code dating to the early 1990s. I do agree that it's pretty useless to ask something ilke this in an interview, but not because ADO.NET 2.0 is obsolete.

Comment: I didn't say it was obsolete. I said it was old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex6y04yf(VS.80).aspx
The person was probably looking for Disconnected Classes

Answer (score 2):

MSDN says [these are the new features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex6y04yf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Well, "he" as in "he said" is right, but MS sure made them work better, faster, and with less coding effort in v2.0.

For one thing, DataReader could be loaded directly into a DataSet or DataTable, which simplified things a lot.  To me the other biggies were the addition of asynchronous BeginExecuteXxxx() & EndExecuteXxxx() calls along with allowing more than one pending request on a connection, and direct support for reading data in a paged manner without having to write a stored procedure for each place you had a large data set that needed to be paged.