# What are the .Net 4.5 new features for Visual Basic?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-8

.net 4.5 is out for Windows 8! What are the new `exciting features` for VB.NET?

Is that worth to download the preview now or should I wait for final release?

Comment: This question is not a good fit for the Stack Overflow format. But [MSDN has a portal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=VS.110).aspx) that may be useful for finding new features for .NET 4.5 and the various languages (scroll to bottom for language links).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/we86c8x2(v=vs.110).aspx Most notable features are async/await and iterator methods (`Yield`) - note that unlike C#, VB supports `Yield` inside lambdas, too, so you effectively get inline lazy sequences.

Comment: @JonH: Agree agree, at P.SE even worse :)

Comment: @stackoverflow coders - I see this question currently has 2 people weighing in on closing this question.  We need a link to balance it - for instance, i don't believe this question should be closed, so I should be able to negate one of those "closes".

Comment: @PavelMinaev I would kinda of say that Async/Await is not new for 4.5 since you can already use it now as a seperate download.

Comment: @JonH - to your first comment/question: probably not, if people would learn to search.

Comment: KevinDTimm - that's one of the things that was mentioned a while back.  You shouldn't have to search Bing / Google for answers, the answers should be posted here...so don't blame the askers of the questions.

Comment: True - so they should learn to search here first (rather than just ask and ask and ask the same questions over and over and over).

Comment: Ok guys, now your turn for reopen votes

Comment: Why wouldn't this question be a good fit for Q&A format? The answers would involve facts and references, and there shouldn't be any debate about new features which have been announced.

Comment: I notice that a very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873303/what-are-the-new-features-of-ado-net-2-0 has not been closed, so I do not think that this should be closed.

Comment: Especially when there is a much better source for the material (the manufacturer of a product) having that material repeated here doesn't seem productive.  (At that point, it's either rehashed or opinion)

Comment: @chrissie1 What's available today for 4.0 is a CTP (i.e. a pre-beta essentially).

Comment: @PavelMinaev true but not new as in you never had and never will have in 4.0 or previous like yield and the namespace thing. But we are talking semantics here and it's not that important.

Answer (score 5):

You will now be able to [override the root namespace](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/in-vb11-the-namespace-difference).

```
Namespace Global.NewNamespace
    Public Class Class1


    End Class
End Namespace

Public Class Class1

End Class
```

Which means the above can be called like this.

```
Dim _class1 As New NewNamespace.Class1
Dim _class1_1 As New VB_Console.Class1
```

And

Iterators are also new.

In other words you get the yield keyword like you already had in C#

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Y0